# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') while using django rest framwork

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I HAVE BEEN TRYING TO GET MY SINGLE BLOG PAGE TO WORK USING AXIOS.GET AND SPECIFYING MY Data using slug in reactjs and djangoREST FRAMEWORK. I keep getting the error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')'. Please help me take a look at these codes. the     home page works but when i try to open the single blog post(post details) i get the TYPEERROR which seems to arise from props.data.params.slug

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class BlogTag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Blog(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(BlogTag, related_name="blog_tags")
    cover = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="media/")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default ="", editable = False, max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = "blog_author", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content =   HTMLField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created_at",)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} - {self.author.username}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="blog_comments",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Annonymous")
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-created_at",)

        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.blog.title} - {self.name}"

router.js

import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/pages/Home/Home'
import SingleBlog from './components/pages/SingleBlogPage/SingleBlog'
import BlogCard from './components/pages/Home/Home'
import BlogCardExtra from './components/pages/Home/Home'
import MainLayout from "./components/Layout/MainLayout"


const Welcome = () => {
  return (
   <Router>
      <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/:slug" exact element={<SingleBlog />} />
      </Routes>
  </Router>
  )
}


export default Welcome



singleblog.js

import React , {useState, useEffect, useParams}  from 'react'
import MainLayout from "../../Layout/MainLayout"
import CommentComp from "../../Common/CommentComp"
import axios from "axios"
import { BLOG_URL } from "../../utils/urls"
import Skeleton from "react-loading-skeleton"
import moment from "moment"

const SingleBlog = (props) => {
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true)
  const [activeBlog, setActiveBlog] = useState([])


  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(BLOG_URL + props.match.params.slug).then(
      (res) => {
        setActiveBlog(res.data)
        setFetching(false)
        console.log(res.data)
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <div className = "singleBlog">
        <div className = "cover-main"  style={{backgroundImage: `url("${!fetching && activeBlog.cover}")`}}/>
        <br />

        <div className="blogListContainer">
          <div className="blogList">
            <h3 key={activeBlog.id}>{activeBlog.title}</h3>
            <div className="author">
              Created by : {activeBlog.author.username}, on {moment(new Date(activeBlog.created_at)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
            </div>
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: activeBlog.content}}/>

              <CommentComp />

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </MainLayout>
  )
}

export default SingleBlog
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've somehow managed to make a `Blog.author` nullable and get a record of `Blog` with `author=NULL`. I believe it's an operational error, you have to fix it on your DB by removing a record and altering a field. Everything else has to be okay.